# Etingof Problem 5.1, "Field embeddings"

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory, representation-theory

Recall that $k(y_1, \dots, y_m)$ denotes the field of rational functions of $y_1, \dots, y_m$ over a field $k$. Let $f : k[x_1, \dots, x_n] \to k(y_1, \dots, y_m)$ be an injective $k$-algebra homomorphism. Show that $m \ge n$. (Look at the growth of dimensions of the spaces $W_N$ of polynomials of degree $N$ in $x_i$ and their images under $f$ as $N \to \infty$). Deduce that if $f: k(x_1, \dots, x_n) \to k(y_1, \dots, y_m)$ is a field embedding, then $m \ge n$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $W_N$ be the space of polynomials with all terms of degree at most $N$. By [Problem 1.38](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-712-introduction-to-representation-theory-fall-2010/lecture-notes/MIT18_712F10_ch1.pdf) of Etingof's notes on representation theory,$$\dim W_N = \sum_{i=0}^N \binom{i+n-1}{n-1}=\binom{N+n}{n}.\tag*{(1)}$$Suppose that $f$ sends $X_i$ to $\frac{P_i(y)}{Q_i(y)}$. Since $f$ is injective and $x_1^{i_1}\dots x_n^{i_n}$ are linearly independent for distinct $n$-tuples $(i_1, \dots, i_n)$ summing to at most $N$, so are $$\left({\frac{P_1(y)}{Q_1(y)}}\right)^{i_1}
\dots \left({\frac{P_n(y)}{Q_n(y)}}\right)^{i_n}.$$Multiplying by $(Q_1 \dots Q_n)^N$, this is equivalent to the linear independence of$$P_1^{i_1}\dots P_n^{i_n} Q_1^{N- i_1} \dots Q_n^{N - i_n}.$$Let $K$ be the maximum degree of the $P_i$, $Q$. Then the degree of the above terms is at most $NK$. Thus they are in the subspace of polynomials in $k[y_1, \dots, y_m]$ with degree at most $NK$, which has degree $\binom{KN+m}{m}$ by $(1)$. Since the dimension of the vector spaces $W_N$ and $f(W_N)$ are equal, and the latter is at most $\binom{KN+m}{m}$,$$\binom{N+n}{n}\leq \binom{KN+m}{m}$$for all $N$. Since the left-hand side is a polynomial of degree $n$ and the right-hand side is a polynomial of degree $m$, we must have $m \ge n$.

Any field embedding $f: k(x_1, \dots, x_n) \to k(y_1, \dots, y_m)$ gives an injective map $f: k[x_1, \dots, x_n] \to k(y_1, \dots, y_m)$, so we must have $m \ge n$ as well.

Comment: It is unclear to me how this is any different from the answer I wrote two hours ago.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an outline:

1)  The dimension of the vector space of degree  $N$ in $n$ variables is $\binom{N+n-1}{n-1}$, this is just combinatorics.  If instead we take the space of all polynomials of degree at most $N$ this has dimension $\binom{N+n}{n}$.In particular if we fix $n$ and let $N$ grow this grows like $cN^{n}$ for some constant $c$.

2)  By combining denominators we can write $f(x_i) = p_i(y)/q(y)$ for some fixed polynomial $q(y)$. Let $d$ be the maximum degree of $q, p_1, p_2, ...,p_n$.  This means that any polynomial of degree at most $N$ gets mapped to a rational function of the form $a(y)/q(y)^N$ where $a(y)$ has degree at most $dN$.

3) So we need to have an injective map from a vector space of dimension ~$cN^n$ to one of dimension ~$c'(dN)^m$ for some fixed constants $c, c', d$ not depending on $N$. Letting $N$ grow to infinity this implies that $m \ge n$.